# Will Deploying Git via Beanstalk affect WordPress Upload Directory Permissions?

Tags: wordpress, git, upload, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a WP site in a workflow that goes local--> git (beanstalk) --> dev server.

Everything seems to be working fine when I deploy, but I've noticed that I can't upload images via WP and it seems like it's a directory permission issue.

The error I get is: "The uploaded file could not be moved to /path/blah/blah...

Is this because the FTP user doesn't 'own' these directories/files (because they weren't created via the WP site / FTP account of the dev server?

Please let me know if you've got any brilliant work-arounds or insights. I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Beanstalk uses ftp to upload your files, that means the owner becomes the FTP user. If Wordpress then wants to access those files, it is no owner so it can't delete/alter them. You can use `chown apache <filename>` on SSH if you want to make apache (wordpress) owner again. But now Beanstalk can't overwrite the files for the same reason.

The way to go is use a .gitignore file to ignore folders like uploads and cache. You don't need them locally for development, if you do, just grab them once with ftp.

I use [this](https://gist.github.com/jdbartlett/444295) one myself with some additions. It may seem weird at first, but it rocks when it all works. :)